# Checksum or sign installation with izpack

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I'm looking for the way to create a checksumn, ,hash or sign of my izpack instalacion.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ant` has a `<checksum>` task which can be used to generate/verify checksum for files.
See [HERE](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html) for `<checksum>` task.